# Using Google App Engine as a Content delivery network

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-app-engine, amazon-s3, heroku, cdn

I would like to know if Google App Engine can be used as a Content delivery network like aws S3. I'm running a RoR app on Heroku and I would like store my uploaded files on GAE instead of s3.

If it's possible what would be the best way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://24ways.org/2008/using-google-app-engine-as-your-own-cdn

It won't be able to host files over 1MB though.

Make sure to read through the comments on that blog post as well, some have concerns about the terms of service.

Comment: They have Blob Storage now (only for paid accounts I think), so maybe the 1MB limit can be relaxed.

Comment: The blobstore allows 10mb files to be uploaded.

Comment: Yeah I know I could just upload files on gae and use it as a server. But by cdn I mean something that can be used for dynamic websites where the user can upload a picture for example. This is what I found so far: http://code.google.com/p/gaevfs/wiki/UsingGaeVFS

Comment: Then perhaps also have a look at http://morethanseven.net/2009/02/05/hosting-images-app-engine.html (code on http://github.com/garethr/appengine-image-host)

Answer (score 0):

GAE in itself isn't meant to be a CDN... that doesn't, however, stop you from writing a CDN application on top of it. The only limit you'll need to worry about is the 50 MB limit on the size of the blobstore. Such an app will have to provide a URL that you can hit to get the upload URL, which could then be used to upload the file. The download url can also be generated with the upload URL, and used to access the content.